# Reload Div content on interval with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

I am trying to modify a page so that I can reload the content of a div on an interval. This is what I tried:

```
    $("#thediv").load("/thecontent.php");
        setTimeout(doPoll,1000);
    }
```

However, using Fiddler reveals that the requests are never made.

Comment: what did `doPoll` do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#thediv").load("thecontent.php");    
    }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: That is not working either. I'm guessing $(document).ready is interfering with the same $(document).ready somewhere in another included JS file. I am not able to modify all these JS files because I do not host them.

Comment: You can have N number of $(document).... probably is something else then that you would need to debug with. The above statements are correct above. Otherwise, please give us a concrete lead on what is happening.

Comment: Issue was `$J = jQuery.noConflict();` had to replace all `$` with `jQuery`

Comment: ahh ha that means you are using more than one framework - probably ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var content = ''; // file
var element = ''; // id or class

$(window).load(function(){

window.setTimeout("doPoll()",1000);

});

function doPoll(){
  (element).load(content);
}
```